# collect the amount of correct number of guessing 4 digit number game

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how to code if I want to know the amount of correct number although dislocating. For example, correct is "7896" but I put "8749" so I want it show that it has "3"(789) that is correct.

```
void Run()
{

    // initialize the number of attempts
    int numberOfAttempts = 1000;

    Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to Random Number Guessing Game.");
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nGuess the 4 digit random number XXXX.");
    Console.WriteLine("\nFor each digit, the number is chosen from 1 to 9  \nNumbers can repeat.");


    // Call the method to Generate the Random Number
    string randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfAttempts; i++)
    {
        // Call the method to get the user input
        string userInput = GetUserInput(i);

        // Get the result - Collection containing the result of all 4 digits
        List<Result> result = GetResult(randomNumber, userInput);

        // Guess the count of number of digits that are correct
        int flagCount = result.Where(f => f.Flag == true).Count();

        // Get the place(s)/index of digits that are correct
        string digitsCorrect = string.Join(",", result.Where(f => f.Flag == true)
            .Select(c => (++c.Index).ToString()));


        // check the flag count and display appropriate message
        if (flagCount == 4)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("Random Number:{0} , Your Input:{1}", randomNumber, userInput);
            Console.WriteLine("You guess is correct! Game Won..hurray...:)");
            break;
        }   
        else
        {

            digitsCorrect = flagCount == 0 ? "none" : digitsCorrect;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Digit(s) in place {0} correct", digitsCorrect));
            Console.WriteLine(flagCount);

        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

i have already done some method and can play already

Comment: What does the `GetResult` method do? What does a `Result` object look like? There is important information missing from the code.

Comment: i have inserted in main question

Comment: `Please help me` is not a question, it's unclear what issue you are having. Can you please update your post to include the actual issue you are having and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
  public static string Info(string guess, string actual)
    {
        int correctNumbers = 0;
        string correctChars = "";

        List<char> charlists = actual.ToList();
        foreach (var char_ in guess)
        {
            if (charlists.Contains(char_))
            {
                correctNumbers++;
                correctChars += char_.ToString();
                charlists.Remove(char_);     
            }
        }
        return $"{correctNumbers}({correctChars})";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is keep track of which digits have already been guessed.  You can do that by creating a dictionary of the digits and checking how many are left unguessed

```
var guess = "7896";
var actual = "8749";

var charCounts = actual.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
var correct = new List<char>();
foreach(char c in guess)
{
    if(charCounts.TryGetValue(c, out var count) && count > 0)
    {
        correct.Add(c);
        charCounts[c]--;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"You guessed {correct.Count} correct digits of {string.Join(",", correct)}");
```

This will then handle the cases of duplicate digits in the actual value and duplicate digits in the guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var input = 8749;
var goal = 7896;
var inputDigits = input.ToString().Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString())).ToList();
var goalDigits = goal.ToString().Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString())).ToList();
var correctDigits = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < goalDigits.Count(); i++)
{
    if(inputDigits.Contains(goalDigits[i]))
    {
        correctDigits.Add(goalDigits[i]);
    }
}
var result = new { correctDigits.Count, correctDigits };
```

Comment: This does not handle duplicate digits in the goal. Change your goal to "7899" and this results in a count of 4 and the list 7,8,9,9. Not to mention that parsing the digits back to ints is unnecessary.  You have to knock out each match as you find it by either keeping track of the count of digits or by removing the match from the list you are comparing to.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
string randomNumber = "7896";
string userInput = "8749";
int result = randomNumber.GroupBy(x => x)
                 .Sum(x => Math.Min(userInput.GroupBy(y => y)
                     .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == x.Key)?.Count() ?? 0, x.Count()));
```